# Faster Active Record Query for counting a group?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization, activerecord

is there a more optimized way to count my records that have been grouped by a column? I just want to count all the records; i dont know why it appears i need to add a select statement before my group method.

```
User.select('username').group('username').to_a.count
```

Comment: `to_a` forces a fetch here, which could be ugly if you have a lot of users. Normally `count` makes a `COUNT(*)` call.

Answer (score 1):

The following will return a hash with username as the key and the count as the value:

```
User.group('username').count
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you just want the count of the distinct usernames, you could use `User.select('distinct username').count`

Comment: or slightly more idiomatically, `User.select(:username).uniq.count`

Comment: I still think you need the SELECT clause here ( unless users table has only one column ).